# How should I enable system services to start on demand?

Tags: boot, services, systemctl

I rarely use virtualbox [on Kubuntu FWIW], it has two system services that load `vboxdrv` and `virtualbox-guest-utils`.

Can I set these services so they **don't load on boot** but **do load on demand**, or do I need to `systemctl disable` them and manually script starting them (eg in a .desktop file)?

What's the general approach?

Thanks.

Comment: You should explain in the question how you think these particular services can be demanded, and what demands them.

Comment: Well, for example if I start a virt machine with vbox it says, inter alia, "The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT." it seems that this is the sort of thing computers do, start services on demand rather than return an error to a user and require the user to `sudo systemctl start $SERVICE`. Could be that this is a "failing" with vbox, that there is a system for it to request services but it doesn't use them; or KDE may not handle services in this way. If I knew I wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 0):

To have a service start on demand instead of on startup/login, enable the socket for the service instead of the service itself.

Do `systemctl disable myservice.service`, followed by `systemctl enable myservice.socket` to have the service start on demand.

See `man systemctl` for more details.

Comment: But I have to create the [socket](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) [file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) first, yes. I must be missing something as I can't quite see why all services wouldn't have a socket file by default - it sounds like using port-knocking to start an internet service?